# AjaxControlToolkit ToolkitScriptManager throws JS error - "ProjectName is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

Occasionally I get a javascript error when I try to call a webservice method.

At the top of my page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="abc" %>
```

Later on...

```
<abc:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnablePageMethods="true">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="getThing.asmx" />
  </Services>
</abc:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

And later down the page, the javascript is in the page:

```
try {
  ret = ProjectName.getThing.GetTheThing(id, oncomplete);
} catch(e) {
  alert(e.message);
}
```

Not always but sometimes I get this javascript alert:

"ProjectName is undefined"

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Which browsers have you tested with?

Comment: The error seems to only happen in IE9. I haven't been able to reproduce it unfortunately... only my client on his computer.